# Should I access cookies from Model or from Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have authentication logic that uses cookies. The model attributes are initialized from cookies, but this is done only when specific controller actions are called.
Should I access my cookies directly from controller logic or make the models even fatter and implement cookies save/load in models?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't clutter your model with web based concerns.  Remember that in theory the model should be relavant in other environments (say if you wanted to provide REST based APIs, or a desktop version).  Access cookies in Controller or Service Layers.

Comment: I would go so far as to say not to get/set cookies in the service layers, unless you use some abstraction wrapper which provides strong typing, as you don't really want magic strings lying around in these layers.